# Единая точка входа в https приложение посредством apache2 mod_rewrite

Tags: apache2, mod-rewrite

Передо мной стоит задача - склонировать продакшн на локальную машину для доработок оффлайн. Прод представляет из себя https сайт с ssl ключами, написан на пхп. Имеет точку входа в единый скрипт, и это осуществлено посредством апача, знаний которого особых у меня нет.

Сначала я, согрешив ленью, через scp тупо перетянул все настройки из /etc/apache2 к себе на машину, и полностью такое же древо путей веб-приложения воссоздал у себя в /var/www, как и там. Так ничего не вышло. На данный момент пытаюсь настроить все с нуля: единую точку входа сделал посредством mod_rewrite, и сайт даже частично заработал у меня, только без картинок и пост-запросов, к сожалению:

apache2.conf :

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/<путь_до_нужной_папки>/>
        Options -ExecCGI -Includes
</Directory>
```

А в "<нужной_папке>" вот такой .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Но так не годится! Теперь я в тупике, и ничего не выходит. Что нужно предпринять? Может вовсе вагрант использовать попытаться, прекратив эти пляски с апачем? А можно ли как-то nginx поставить, и все конфиги апача конвертировать в nginx'овские? Или воевать дальше? Конфиги там большие, и реально трудно  что-то предпринять, не зная апача. Я понимаю, как это выглядит со стороны, но все же попрошу указать мне, хотя бы абстрактный, порядок моих действий.

---

Вопрос: как воссоздать точку входа к скрипту в определенной папке https-сайта, без потери данных POST-запросов?

Comment: здесь принята модель: вы задаёте вопрос, вам отвечают. переформулируйте, пожалуйста, то, что вы написали, так, чтобы это было вопросом, а не только изложением возникших у вас проблем и требований. исправления можно внести, нажав [edit] ниже текста (пока ещё не) вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `AllowOverride`  вы ставлено в `None`, что запрещает использование `.htaccess`

Варианта два:

1)`AllowOverride All`

2) Все ваши правила `mod_rewrite` переписать в общий конфиг:

```
<Directory /var/www/путь_до_нужной_папки/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

    # Ваши привила
</Directory>
```

Второй вариант предпочтительнее, ибо

> You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down your Apache http server.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#page-header

Да, и уберите дефолтные настройки:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

В идеале в `apache2.conf` не должно быть никаких правил. В общем конфиге должны указаны:

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Собственно, в директория `sites-available` создаём конфиги с правилами и делаем симлинки в `sites-enabled`.

К примеру, конфиг для приложения `site.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site.com
  #ServerAlias www.site.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/путь_до_нужной_папки/

 <Directory /var/www/путь_до_нужной_папки/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Require all granted
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On  

        # Redirect /index.php to /
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\ /index\.(?:php|htm|html)(\?.*)?\ HTTP/
        RewriteRule ^.*$ /%1 [R=301,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Данные настройки актуальны для Apache 2.4. В 2.2 немного по другому.

---

Если ваш сервер под Linux могу предложить воспользоваться подготовленным мной [Docker контейнером](https://github.com/romeOz/docker-apache-php) с Apache + PHP 5.3-5.6

```
docker run --name app -d -p 8080:80 \
  -v /host/to/path/app:/var/www/app/ \
  romeoz/docker-apache-php
```

, где `/host/to/path/app` директория с вашим приложением.

Для Nginx [тоже имеется](https://github.com/romeOz/docker-nginx-php).

Comment: Спасибо за отклик! Сделал все по Вашей инструкции - без изменений ( Когда убрал дефолтные настройки - сервер локальный перестал функционировать (

Comment: @Matvey Safronov: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: спасибо за потраченное время. Я сделал новый конфиг и символическую ссылку к нему, как и сказали. Сделал отдельно даже хост в /etc/hosts. В конечном счете ничего не изменилось. После изменений регулярно перезапускаю апач, и смотрю логи в /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/access.log - мои запросы в нем есть, все ок

На сервере версия апача:
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

У меня локально:
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

Может в этом причина?

Comment: @MatveySafronov, попробуйте закомментировать в `index.php` всю логику и вывести только `echo 'Hello world!'`. Если в конфиге Apache 2.4 были бы невиалидные конструкции (к примеру, используемые только в 2.2), то access.log был пустым, а ошибки валились в error.log  с указанием строчки, где по мнению Apache существует синтаксическая ошибка.

Comment: Так разумеется все выводится. Я точно "смотрю" нужный сайт, и он работает, но без пост-запросов ( наверное тут уже ничем не помочь, и в самом сайте есть какие-то переадресации и т.д., апач наверное не при чем. трудно вообщем все тут (

Comment: romeo, тут выясняется еще связка с nginx на сервере,вообщем там такой огород, что просто нужно идти другим путем. большое спасибо!

Comment: @MatveySafronov, давайте чтобы окончательно убедиться, что "собака зарыта" в приложении, сделаем CURL запрос. В `index.php` укажите только `echo $_POST['foo'];`. Далее в консоле  `curl -X POST "site.com" --data "foo=value"`, где `site.com` ваш локальных домен, возможно `localhost`. Должна отобразиться строчка `value`.

Comment: таким образом в терминал вывелась верстка до </html>

Comment: @Matvey Safronov: ошибка 404/500, что за верстка? `curl -i -X POST "site.com" --data "foo=value"` Ключ `i` указывает на вывод заголовок, а не тела запроса.

Comment: у меня допустим http://asd/ локально расположен сайт. я пишу: curl -i -X POST "asd" --data "foo=value" , в консоль выводится верстка до тега </html> , если там сверху выводятся http-заголовки, то мне не видно их, не добраться. Напишите в лс (не могу увидеть,как это сделать здесь), чтобы не "засорять" комментарии! спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^()$ index.php/ [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Спасибо за отклик. К сожалению, все осталось неизменным - пост запросы не передаются (в пхп сделал вывод $_POST - оно пустое всегда). Примечательно, что вместе с контентом я получаю статус 404 ...